# How to decrypt McAfee EPo drive / partitions manually after broken boot loader?

Tags: boot, disk-encryption, decryption

Windows 8.1 laptop disk was encrypted with McAfee End Point Encryption (EPo) software.

Something was done with boot loader and boot of OS was coruppted (I don't know exactly), now data on C and D drives cannot be retrieved as these partitions still encrypted.

I have created with DD full drive copy and copies of partitions (C,D - sda4 and sda5), how I can decrypt these partitions with my encryption password manually?

Is there exist correct procedure to do this? We contacted McAfee but no response yet.

I have used Kali live USB to check and can confirm that data still exist, just in encrypted partitions. Parted, Testdisk utils can c GPT partition table.

Just to clarify - Laptop is completely unbootable so access from EPo console impossible, manual recovery would be required.

Following partitions can be seen currently:

*sda1 -> NTFS (300MB)

sda2 -> EFI (100MB)

sda3 -> Basic Data Partition (50MB)-> I am suspecting that this partition belongs to McAfee.

sda4 -> Basic Data Partition (around 100GB -> this is my C drive) -> Appears as RAW

sda5 -> Basic Data Partition (around 100GB -> this is my D drive) -> Appears as RAW*

Please note - I am not McAfee expert, so would appreciate any guidance on this.

Comment: so is McAfee a FDE solution?

Comment: Yes, it is called actually as EPo